# SageMaker BlazingText Importing a FastText model and continue training

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, fasttext

I would like to start off a pretrained FastText model such as [these](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html), and continue training on a different dataset and finally export back the trained model.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Incremental Training. [Link to documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/incremental-training.html)

Comment: SageMaker BlazingText currently doesn't support incremental training.